# Android Virtual Device Created from SDK 22 occupies whole screen

Tags: size, screen, android-virtual-device

I am using `SDK 22.0.1` , and I created a virtual device with the specification listed below. I observed that devices created via `SDK 22` need to select a Device and then API Level. I selected Device as `4.7" WXGA` and `API 15` but `AVD` created as a result of this is looking like a tablet. Please advise.